# Regex replace all except of this string

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a **XAML document** and I want to select all texts with Regex with this form:

```
Default=xyz}
```

I wrote for it this very simple regex and it works:

```
Default=.+}
```

Now, how do I exactly the opposite? I want to delete all other text than this in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find: `.*(Default=[^}]+}).*`

Replace with: `\1`